# Excel Macros not visible after Office update

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook in which I consolidate data from various CSV files. There are a number of macros in this file including ones to add new sheets to the file, which is on a shortcut key Ctrl+Shift+N. This has been working perfectly for many years. This morning the shortcut key does absolutely nothing. If I go to the Excel developer tab and click on the Macros button, the list of macros is empty. However, if I open VBA I can run the macro from there and it still works perfectly.

I run Office Professional Plus 2019 and it ran an update yesterday. Does anyone know of a new setting introduced that may hide the macros in Excel itself. Note that macros are enabled on this workbook.

Comment: Not that I am aware of.. Can you check couple of things? **1.** Is `All Open Workbooks` is selected from the Macros in listbox? **2.** Is your  `Sub` is stated as private? For example `Private Sub Sample()?` **3.** Was the workbook converted to an Add-In recently?

Comment: Hi Siddharth. All Open Workbooks selected. Sub is public. File is not an add-in, just a macro-enabled workbook .xlsm

Comment: Possible to see the file? If yes, then can you share it on a free file sharing platform and paste the link here. Ensure to remove any confidential information before posting

Comment: Try saving the file in the binary format `xlsb`. Do not rename but open ary save it and check the right format (not only the extension). See if this file has the same issue.

Comment: @SiddharthRout: Unfortunately the file contains sensitive client data so I cannot share

Comment: @Pᴇʜ: I saved it as xlsb (binary format) and still the same issue

Comment: That is why i said to remove the confidential data. Create a copy of that file. Insert a blank sheet and delete rest of the sheets. Now share the file.

Comment: The problem seems to be with the specific file as a previous version is still working correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for closure should someone else stumble across this. The problem was related to the specific file. It somehow got "partially" corrupted. Still worked and could fire macros from VBA IDE as well as linked buttons, just not with shortcut keys as macros not "visible" in Excel view. File degraded further to a point where it could no longer save.

Comment: If this was a `xlsx` or `xlsm` file I recommend to try the binary `xlsb` format (it can contain macros too). This turns out to be much more stable against corruptions than the other 2 xlm formats. I had many corruptions `xlsx`/`xlsm` but never with `xlsb`. Further the files are even smaller in size (especially with big data).